# Join data from two tables without unique key

Tags: sql, database, join

I have two tables in one database (access file).

**Table 1**:

```
| Product Id |  Year     | Sales |
----------------------------------
| 1144       |  2013     | 100   |
| 20131120   |  2013     | 200   |
| 1144       |  2012     | 333   |
```

**Table 2**:

```
| Product Id     |  Category     |
----------------------------------
| 1144           | Car           |
| 20131120       | Motorbike     |
```

The first table (table 1) is the table when user can add new data whenever wants, and the second table is updated once in a while, when new product id appears. I would like to join this table, some kind of relation on the base of Product Id, but I'm not able to use relation due to the lack of unique, primary key, am I right? When I execute SQL query ( `SELECT * FROM Table 1`) I would like to get the result like this one:

```
| Product Id |  Year     | Sales | Category   |
-----------------------------------------------
| 1144       |  2013     | 100   | Car        |
| 20131120   |  2013     | 200   | Motrobike  |
| 1144       |  2012     | 333   | Car        |
```

I know I can join this two tables, but I would like not to do it every time when user add new data to table 1. Do you know any solution how could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not able to use relation due to the lack of unique, primery key,
>   am I right?

No, this is not right, you can normally `JOIN` the two tables. It’s also legal to `JOIN` two tables or result sets on any columns that have what so called eligible data types.

```
SELECT
  t1.ProductId, t1.year, t1.sales, t2.category
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.productId = t2.productId;
```

---

> but I would like not to do it every time when user add new data to
>   table 1

You don't need a `ProductId` in the second table, you need a `CategoryId` instead, and add a new column `CategoryId` to the first table too and declare it as a foreign key. Your tables should look like so:

**`Table1`** (Products):

- `ProductId`,
- `CategoryId`,
- `Year`,
- `Sales`.

**`Table2`** (Categories):

- `CategoryId`,
- `CategoryName`.

Then the category is added once to the categories table `table2` and the product is added once to the products table `table1`. And for each product enter a `CategoryId` for it. This what so called [**normalization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

You should also define `ProductId` in table1 and `CategoryID` in table2 as primary keys, and `CategoryID` in the first table as foreign key.

Comment: Thank You very much. I created relationship on the base of this fields. Now I would like to execute SELECT query on Table 1 and beyond ProductId, Year, Sales I would like to see also CategoryName. I guess it's quite easy but I was not able to do it. Could you helpe me?

Comment: @user2674174 - You're welcome any time :) The query I posted in my answer should do what you want, it will select the categoryname too like this `SELECT
  t1.ProductId, t1.year, t1.sales, t2.category
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.productId = t2.productId;`. Have you tried it?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought it would work more automatically when I created relationship between the tables and I could only operate on Table 1 and get also information from table 2. I can use INNER JOIN statement without defining relation.